# Clear cach in amplify on deploy

Tags: vue.js, caching, deployment, web-deployment, aws-amplify

I have a VUE PWA app in Amazon Amplify,
I can't see any changes when I deploy, only after I clear cache on the browser, I can see the changes.
When I do any changes on the app, I do `git push origin/master` and I see the app finish the build process but not see the changes until I clear the cache.

Any help how can I clear the cache or see the changes faster?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: Yes, it happened because the Service Worker, I change it default behavior to "skip waiting" and everything worked fine.

Comment: I uninstall service worker, removed it from code but it is still happening.  Looks like a bug to me.